# Process Created By Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) is sleeping in middle of execution

Tags: java

```
File jarFile = new File(jarLocation + "/myJar.jar");
if ((jarFile).exists()) {
    String[] command = new String[10];
    command[0] = "java";
    command[1] = "-jar";
    command[2] = jarFile + "";
    command[3] = Data.getParam1() + "";
    command[4] = Data.getParam2() + "";
    command[5] = Data.getParam3();
    command[6] = Data.getParam4() + "";
    command[7] = Data.getParam5() + "";
    command[8] = "2";
    command[9] = Data.getParam6() + "";
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
}
```

When I execute my jar on terminal it works fine. However, when I try to execute the same jar using the above code, the process which executes this jar goes in sleep state without completing its execution. So please do suggest how I can complete the execution of the jar in one go.

Comment: How do you say that it goes to sleep state?

Comment: You have to ensure you are reading the output and the error stream. If these buffers fill up, the process waits until you read them.

Answer (score 0):

In java, the sub-process that is created uses the parent's console. The blocking could be because of failure to read the input stream or write the output. Perhaps when running the jar directly from the terminal, it works as the console probably is assigned to the process (Don't quote me though).

check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html